# Bootstrap 3 Popover Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've searched for an answer as to why popovers aren't working. I checked my JS file (the most updated version) for the popover code and it is there. Jquery works on the navigation and the carousel on the homepage. I copied and pasted the code for the button directly from Bootstrap's website. What am I doing wrong?

Go to this page to see the problem: http://staging.ceobusinessalliance.com/site-selectors/creative-incentives/ It is the button at the very top.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the popover functionality first, as is stated in the bootstrap docs:

> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning **you must initialize them yourself**.

You can do this by including this little script at the end of your html:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

[Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/VaOCefRiZf)

And next time please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new#) of your problem, so that we don't have to search your entire site.. ;)

Comment: I read that note but I thought that meant to select tooltip and popover when creating a custom version of Bootstrap. Next time I will provide the code. Thank you so much!! :)